# 2 methods for getting location in wp8, which is best?

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8

In wp8 as far as I can see there are 2 methods for getting the location from a Geolocator.

1. Listen to the PositionChanged event
2. Use GetPositionAsync

In my app I wish to get the location say every 5 seconds. Does it matter which of the above I use? Or is one method better suited for frequent location capture than the other?

Comment: 1. is fired when the position have *changed*, 2. is getting you the *current* position async.

Answer (score 5):

That's not how GeoLocation works on WP7/WP8.

Windows Phone gets location information from multiple sources (GPS, GLONASS, WiFi, Cell Towers, homing pigeons, etc) and caches it for future use. The way the WP7/WP8 Location Services APIs work is that they always get new information and depending on your DesiredAccuracy and your MinimumThreshold will decide to bubble up events to the managed/WinPRT APIs. Again, events are time based. Events firing in the Location Services API are based on the availability of new data that would be useful to your specific criterion.

If you want to perform an action every 5 seconds based on GeoLoc, you best bet it to subscribe to the events from GeoLocator/GeoCoordinateWatcher, cache the latest value in your app and every 5 seconds use the latest value. Don't count on geolocation events firing every 5 seconds and don't poll the WinPRT APIs using GetPositionAsync(). GetPositionAsync() is there for one-time geolocation acquisition scenarios, not tracking scenarios.

Comment: But what if you have a MovementThreshold of say 1 meter which could be used in a running app. If the UI thread is having to update the stats on the displays such as speed and distance, wouldn't the event triggering of the movement hit performance and cause delays in the update?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the position every 5 minutes or so, I'd use GetPositionAsync as that will allow you to retrieve the data when you want to. Using the event could mean that you end up retrieving data whenever the user moves, which may cause you problems.

Comment: Every 5 seconds or did you actually mean 5 minutes?

Comment: @Gaz83 - Sorry, I meant seconds and, for some odd reason, I typed minutes. The main problem with using the event is that every time the user moves and the position updates the event will fire. Which one you want to use kind of depends on the exact purpose of the program, but based on what you've said it sounds to me like calling GetPositionAsync when you need to would work best.